# R: 'from' must be of length 1

Tags: r, datagrid, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to define a grid using the "expand.grid" command, where the grid "self references" itself:

```
random_1 <- seq(80,100,5)
random_2 <- seq(random_1,120,5)
random_3 <- seq(85,120,5)
random_4 <- seq(random_3,120,5)
split_1 =  seq(0,1,0.5)
split_2 =  seq(0,1,0.5)
split_3 =  seq(0,1,0.5)
DF_2 <- expand.grid(random_1 , random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(random_3, 120, 5) : 'from' must be of length 1
>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq` takes a single element as `from`, `to`.  According to `?seq`

> from, to - the starting and (maximal) end values of the sequence. Of length 1 unless just from is supplied as an unnamed argume

We could loop over the 'random_1'

```
lapply(random_1, function(x) seq(x, 120, 5))
```

---

Do the same for `random_3` and construct as

```
> random_2 <- lapply(random_1, function(x) seq(x, 120, 5))
> random_3 <- seq(85,120,5)
> random_4 <- lapply(random_3, function(x) seq(x, 120, 5))
> split_1 =  seq(0,1,0.5)
> split_2 =  seq(0,1,0.5)
> split_3 =  seq(0,1,0.5)
> DF_2 <- expand.grid(c(list(random_1), random_2, random_3, random_4, list(split_1, split_2, split_3)))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! what is "function(x)" ?

Comment: @stats555 it is a lambda/anonymous function ie. function created on the fly.  Usually we create functions as `f1 <- function(x) do this`.  instead, we can use `function(x) do this` when the expression is short

Comment: @ akrun: thank you for your reply! I will accept your answer as soon the clock allows me. Can you please show me how to incorporate this "lapply" statement into the grid?

Comment: @stats555 please note that there is a limit for expand.grid.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please take a look at this question if you have time later? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 which question you want to look at

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565000/r-feeding-functions-using-grids

Comment: Thanks again! Really appreciate it!